# Print void pointer in a Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have an array of structs called arrayOfElements , the structs are called Elements which have a void pointer

```
typedef struct {
    void* data;
} Element;
```

Ive malloc'd arrayOfElements

```
Element* arrayOfElements;
arrayOfElements= malloc(4 * sizeof(Element));
```

and have stored ints and strings in the strucs

```
arrayOfElements[3].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
ptr = arrayOfElements[3].data;
*ptr = 65;
```

strcpy(arrayOfElements[1].data, token );

Then I have created a Linked List

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
    void* arrayOfStruct;
    struct LinkedList* next;
} LinkedList;
```

And have created a function to import a instance of arrayOfELements and make void* arrayOfStruct point to it

```
LinkedList* insert(LinkedList* head, Element* inArrayOfElements) { 
    LinkedList* insertNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    insertNode->next = head;
    insertNode->arrayOfStruct = (void*)inArrayOfElements;

    return insertNode;
}
```

**Question**

My question is after I have pointed void* arrayOfStruc to an instance of arrayOfELements, how do I print void* data of arrayOfElements[3] which I know from before is an int and its value is 65

Current Node in LinkedList ---> arrayOfElements[3] --> data member in Element struct (should equal 65)

I have a feeling I should point a int pointer to it and then print that, but Im not sure the syntax to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some way of knowing what kind of data the `data` member points to.  An additional element denoting the type would work.

```
typedef enum {
    STR_TYPE,
    INT_TYPE,
    ...
} data_type;

typedef struct {
    data_type type;
    void* data;
} Element;
```

Then you can set the element like this:

```
arrayOfElements[3].type = INT_TYPE;
arrayOfElements[3].data = malloc( sizeof(int) );
int *ptr = arrayOfElements[3].data;
*ptr = 65;

arrayOfElements[1].type = STR_TYPE;
strcpy(arrayOfElements[1].data, token );
```

and read it like this:

```
Element *curr = &list_node->arrayOfStruct[3];
if (curr->type == INT_TYPE) {
    int *pint = curr->data;
    printf("int data = %d\n", *pint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i didnt even think of setting a type variable. Is &list_node a pointer to the current node im in? ( or what ever node I want to read from) , so then curr points to arrayOfStruct[3] ?